# Limiting Twitter API results to tweets sent to all users (no @replies)?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to find a way to just get tweets to all users.  The JSON code indicates these as "to_user" null.  For example the tweet below edent tweets to everyone, thus the to_user=null.
I tried a few alternatives without success:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to:null%20from:edent&result_type=mixed
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to:0%20from:edent&result_type=mixed
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to:%20from:edent&result_type=mixed

{
        "created_at": "Thu, 28 Jun 2012 06:55:58 +0000",
        "from_user": "edent",
        "from_user_id": 14054507,
        "from_user_id_str": "14054507",
        "from_user_name": "Terence Eden",
        "geo": null,
        "id": 218236278402068480,
        "id_str": "218236278402068480",
        "iso_language_code": "en",
        "metadata": {
            "result_type": "recent"
        },
        "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2318692719/7182974111_ec8e1fb46f_s_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2318692719/7182974111_ec8e1fb46f_s_normal.jpg",
        "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;",
        "text": "RT @straczynski: @edent Clearly the man was ahead of his time.",
        "to_user": null,
        "to_user_id": 0,
        "to_user_id_str": "0",
        "to_user_name": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": 218075066452287500,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "218075066452287488"
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're just looking to get tweets from a particular user that aren't to anyone, use the [/get/statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) REST API endpoint instead of the Search API. /get/statuses/user_timeline has an exclude_replies parameter that should do what you're looking for.

The Search API doesn't have any way to exclude replies. Your only option is to get tweets matching whatever other parameters you pass, and process them on your end to remove any whose text starts with "@".